# How to test an Android Auto App

Tags: android-testing, android-auto

I downloaded the API Simulators for the Android Auto Apps as it is said in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/index.html) but I do not see it appearing on the categories of the AVD Manager. I am doing something wrong / do I have to do something else in order to test an App that I created for trying it out?

[image: Android Auto App Testing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the your SDK folder -> extras -> google -> simulators and install the "media-browser-simulator.apk" in the device you want to test your app and Voila.

Comment: I understood it all wrong and did not think I could try it on an actual device. I thought it would detect it was a mobile and would display it as a regular app. Thanks!